# Is IMongoCollection.AsQueryable() Deferred?

Tags: c#, mongodb, repository-pattern, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm new to mongodb, and trying to implement Repository pattern using mongodb in my app. So my question is when I query db using below query:

```
_mongodb.GetCollection<T>(typeof(T).Name.ToLower()).AsQueryable();
```

Will it fetch all the records into memory or is the result a deferred collection which will get data when I iterate it or use ToList on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is deferred. It won't fetch results into the memory unless you request the data or a perform a manipulation on it. as you mention as example `.ToList()` or `.First()` or `.Count()` or iterate over it.

**EDIT:**

Even though it might not be documented, you can prove that with a simple test. Enable logging for mongodb and execute the line you mentioned in your question; you shouldn't see a query. and then execute .ToList() in another line and you will see the query in the log.

Enable logging (an example) from [the official documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/what_is_new/#logging) :

```
var settings = new MongoClientSettings
{
    ClusterConfigurator = cb =>
    {
        var textWriter = TextWriter.Synchronized(new StreamWriter("mylogfile.txt"));
        cb.AddListener(new LogListener(textWriter));
    }
};
```

Comment: @Sirraj Mansour: can you give some resource on this, I searched around found nothing, and mongo documentation for this is a just one liner and does not mention anything about deferred results